# StarActivityForResult() leading to force close on returning Intent data

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Here's a section of my code :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_settings:

        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Settings.class),1);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data) {

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // This was causing the error. See the fantastic answer that's been provided for details. Comment out this this and it works !

    if(requestCode==1) {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) 
        {
            String extraData=data.getData().toString();

            minD=Integer.parseInt(extraData);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),minD, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    }

}
```

Here's the code for Settings.java

```
package com.example.com.draft1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Settings extends Activity  {



@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);


    Button setbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetminDistance);


    setbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

        //Intent data=new Intent();
        EditText mind=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.minDistance);
                    String minDis =mind.getText().toString();
                    Intent data = new Intent();   
                    data.setData(Uri.parse(minDis));

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), minDis, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  //  intent.putExtra("minD", minDis);





       if (getParent() == null) {
           setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
       } else {
           getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
       }
       finish();



      /*  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
       finish();*/
            }

});

}
}
```

Now when I choose the menu option for **Settings** , the required activity opens up perfectly , however , when i attempt to return data , it leads to a force close

Here's the Logcat reading that shows the error :

```
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=65 }} to activity {com.example.com.draft1/com.example.com.draft1.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at com.example.com.draft1.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:570)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
09-29 16:03:29.366: E/AndroidRuntime(766):  ... 11 more
```

Why am i encountering a force close here ?

I'd really appreciate help here

Thanks for the interest in the question

**As Per Suggestions**

```
if(requestCode==1) {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) 
        {
            //String extraData=data.getData().toString();

            //minD=Integer.parseInt(extraData);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: `Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1"`

Comment: @Keyser thanks for your reply. Could you please explain ? I'm new to android , hence I'm facing a little difficulty understanding the Logcat entry

Comment: Sorry, can't give you much more, but that's the reason for the force close. Look over all your string resource code.

Comment: @CapDroid I've edited the question to include the full Logcat error

Comment: your error in this class MainActivity at line 570 .. what at this line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see [**Toast.makeText**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29)

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, int resId, int duration)
```

So if you giving second parameter as `int` then system will look for this id in R.java but irony is actually you wanting to print number so just cast your second parameter to `String` i.e. [**this**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29)

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Change Toast line code to

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),requestCode+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),String.valueOf(requestCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.However , I still get the same force close error

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately it's still giving me a force close error.I've edited my questions to reflect the code as per your suggestion.

Comment: Okay , so I'd made a silly error. Learnt something crucial from your answer.Thanks a ton :D

Answer (score 0):

you should use mIntent.putExtra instead of uri...
check this code....

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_settings:
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Settings.class), 1);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            minD = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("data"));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(minD), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    }

}`
```

**Setting.java**

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);

    Button setbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SetminDistance);

    setbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText mind = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.minDistance);
            Intent data = getIntent();
            data.putExtra("data", mind.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), mind.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (getParent() == null) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            } else {
                getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            }
            finish();
        }

    });

}
```

}